# function not returning string values

Tags: python, function, return-value

I would like to return the string values of m & t from my message function to use in cipher function to perform a while loop and once false print the message reverse. The error message I am receiving is "NameError: name 'm' is not defined", but 'm' has been defined in message which i am attempting to return for use in cipher along with 't'.

```
def main():
    message()
    cipher(m, t)


def message():
    m = input("Enter your message: ")
    t = ''
    return m, t


def cipher(m, t):
    i = len(m) - 1
    while i >= 0:
        t = t + m[i]
        i -= 1
    print(t)


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Comment: m is not defined in `main()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you call your `message()` function, you need to store the return values.

```
def main():
    m, t = message()
    cipher(m, t)
```

Comment: That worked! Thank You. Whenever I want to return a value from a function in python will I need to do this ?

Comment: You could also do `cipher(message())`. Functions only return values. Variables declared in functions do not leave the scope of the function they are called in. Scope is a really important concept in all programming languages that I know of. http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html